msys2 pacman hanging when asked to install SDL2
I want to make my program cross-platform. It's already working on Mac, using VS code and GCC toolchain. So I go to set up the same on Windows, and I install MSYS2. Time to build: I have a dependency on SDL2, need to go get it.  MSYS2 seems to use the pacman package manager, so I type
$ pacman -S sdl2
to the MSYS2 command window.
Result: radio silence, pacman seems to hang for 10 to 15 minutes. At length it says "Interrupt signal received" although I really don't think I typed control-C at it.
Second try:
$ pacman --verbose --debug -S sdl2
This gives the somewhat extensive output shown at the end of this message, which appears to be all preliminaries not the real thing – and then hangs for hours.
pacman -Q  in another window does not show sdl2 listed.
Looking for suggestions: how to approach this? Is there a better package manager I should be using? Is this failing because I am running on ARM hardware rather than Intel? Is there any way to further diagnose the situation?
By the way, this is repeatable: I came to exactly the same impasse on a similar VM a couple of months ago.  pacman neither succeeds nor reports failure on this package, it appears to get stuck in a loop.
Environment:
Windows 11 Pro
running in a VM under Parallels version 20
under Mac OS 14.2.1
MacBook Pro, Apple M1 Max processor

Debug output:
$ pacman --verbose --debug -S sdl2
debug: pacman v6.0.2 - libalpm v13.0.2
debug: config: attempting to read file /etc/pacman.conf
debug: config: new section 'options'
debug: config: HoldPkg: pacman
debug: config: Architecture: auto
debug: config: arch: x86_64
debug: config: SigLevel: Required
debug: config: LocalFileSigLevel: Optional
debug: config: new section 'clangarm64'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 74: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw
debug: config: new section 'mingw32'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 77: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw
debug: config: new section 'mingw64'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 80: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw
debug: config: new section 'ucrt64'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 83: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw
debug: config: new section 'clang32'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 86: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw
debug: config: new section 'clang64'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 89: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw
debug: config: new section 'msys'
debug: config file /etc/pacman.conf, line 92: including /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.msys
debug: config: finished parsing /etc/pacman.conf
debug: setup_libalpm called
debug: option 'logfile' = /var/log/pacman.log
debug: option 'gpgdir' = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
debug: option 'hookdir' = /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
debug: option 'cachedir' = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
debug: registering sync database 'clangarm64'
debug: database path for tree clangarm64 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/clangarm64.db
debug: GPGME version: 1.23.2
debug: GPGME engine info: file=/usr/bin/gpg, home=/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/clangarm64.db
debug: 1 signatures returned
debug: fingerprint: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57
debug: summary: valid
debug: summary: green
debug: status: Success
debug: timestamp: 1714937978
debug: exp_timestamp: 0
debug: validity: full; reason: Success
debug: key: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57, Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter.christoph@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
debug: signature is valid
debug: signature is fully trusted
debug: setting usage of 15 for clangarm64 repository
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.msys2.org/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.umd.edu/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/msys2.org/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/windows/msys2/builds/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.nju.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://repo.extreme-ix.org/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.clarkson.edu/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.archlinux.tw/MSYS2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://fastmirror.pp.ua/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/msys2-mirror/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.aliyun.com/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clangarm64': https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/msys2/mingw/clangarm64
debug: registering sync database 'mingw32'
debug: database path for tree mingw32 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db
debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db
debug: 1 signatures returned
debug: fingerprint: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57
debug: summary: valid
debug: summary: green
debug: status: Success
debug: timestamp: 1714937884
debug: exp_timestamp: 0
debug: validity: full; reason: Success
debug: key: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57, Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter.christoph@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
debug: signature is valid
debug: signature is fully trusted
debug: setting usage of 15 for mingw32 repository
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.msys2.org/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.umd.edu/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/msys2.org/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/windows/msys2/builds/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.nju.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://repo.extreme-ix.org/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.clarkson.edu/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.archlinux.tw/MSYS2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://fastmirror.pp.ua/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/msys2-mirror/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.aliyun.com/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw32': https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/msys2/mingw/mingw32
debug: registering sync database 'mingw64'
debug: database path for tree mingw64 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw64.db
debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw64.db
debug: 1 signatures returned
debug: fingerprint: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57
debug: summary: valid
debug: summary: green
debug: status: Success
debug: timestamp: 1714937856
debug: exp_timestamp: 0
debug: validity: full; reason: Success
debug: key: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57, Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter.christoph@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
debug: signature is valid
debug: signature is fully trusted
debug: setting usage of 15 for mingw64 repository
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.msys2.org/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.umd.edu/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/msys2.org/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/windows/msys2/builds/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.nju.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://repo.extreme-ix.org/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.clarkson.edu/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.archlinux.tw/MSYS2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://fastmirror.pp.ua/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/msys2-mirror/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.aliyun.com/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'mingw64': https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/msys2/mingw/mingw64
debug: registering sync database 'ucrt64'
debug: database path for tree ucrt64 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/ucrt64.db
debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/ucrt64.db
debug: 1 signatures returned
debug: fingerprint: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57
debug: summary: valid
debug: summary: green
debug: status: Success
debug: timestamp: 1714937903
debug: exp_timestamp: 0
debug: validity: full; reason: Success
debug: key: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57, Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter.christoph@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
debug: signature is valid
debug: signature is fully trusted
debug: setting usage of 15 for ucrt64 repository
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.msys2.org/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.umd.edu/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/msys2.org/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/windows/msys2/builds/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.nju.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://repo.extreme-ix.org/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.clarkson.edu/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.archlinux.tw/MSYS2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://fastmirror.pp.ua/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/msys2-mirror/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.aliyun.com/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: adding new server URL to database 'ucrt64': https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/msys2/mingw/ucrt64
debug: registering sync database 'clang32'
debug: database path for tree clang32 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/clang32.db
debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/clang32.db
debug: 1 signatures returned
debug: fingerprint: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57
debug: summary: valid
debug: summary: green
debug: status: Success
debug: timestamp: 1714937961
debug: exp_timestamp: 0
debug: validity: full; reason: Success
debug: key: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57, Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter.christoph@gmail.com>, owner_trust unknown, disabled 0
debug: signature is valid
debug: signature is fully trusted
debug: setting usage of 15 for clang32 repository
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.msys2.org/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.umd.edu/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/msys2.org/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/windows/msys2/builds/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.nju.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://repo.extreme-ix.org/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.clarkson.edu/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.archlinux.tw/MSYS2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://fastmirror.pp.ua/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/msys2-mirror/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.aliyun.com/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: adding new server URL to database 'clang32': https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/msys2/mingw/clang32
debug: registering sync database 'clang64'
debug: database path for tree clang64 set to /var/lib/pacman/sync/clang64.db
debug: checking signature for /var/lib/pacman/sync/clang64.db
debug: 1 signatures returned
debug: fingerprint: 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57
debug: summary: valid
debug: summary: green
debug: status: Success
debug: timestamp: 1714937934
debug: exp_timestamp: 0
debug: validity: full; reason: Success
<and here it hangs>


Try adding the installation directory to antivirus exceptions. If this doesn't work, I'd ask MSYS2 devs.

I made https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2 which I use to cross-compile from Linux, you could try it on your Linux VM.

@HolyBlackCat, Just to clarify, this is a Windows VM.  Are you suggesting are you suggesting that I should build a Linux VM in order to help debug this?  Does it matter what flavor of Linux?

"Try adding the installation directory to antivirus exceptions.”  I'm sorry, could you expand on that? Where are these antivirus exceptions? I didn't find them in Windows settings. And where is pacman going to install things? Or do you mean some other installation directory?

Somewhere in the Windows Defender settings. I mean C:\msys64, or whereever you installed MSYS2 to.

"Just to clarify, this is a Windows VM." I know. "Are you suggesting are you suggesting that I should build a Linux VM in order to help debug this?" Not to debug, just to have something working. "Does it matter what flavor of Linux?" Hopefully not. If your preferred distro doesn't work, report me a bug.

An update of MSYS2 improved the situation, now instead of hanging it tells me that  it can't find the package sdl2. error: target not found: sdl2 Does that sound probable?I would have thought that package was more widely distributed. How might I look to be really, really sure that it simply isn't out there?

You're using the wrong package name, you want mingw-w64-...-SDL2. As for what ... to pick, consult What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?. Usually ... = ucrt-x86_64.

Wow that caught me off guard! In no other system or package manager  have I had to think about such things! But it's getting packages now. Two keys: 1. I needed to capitalize SDL2, not true everywhere.  2. pacman -Ss sdl2 revealed all.  Thanks, I’m past that hurdle!

Yep! Also be careful what compiler you install, it should be mingw-w64-...-gcc not gcc. And when compiling, make sure to open the terminal using the matching shortcut to have it in the PATH (MSYS2 UCRT64 for ...=ucrt-x86_64).
